# fetch lookup fields value on div and set a input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I managed to grab all calculated values on group of div and set the total, but they want to only show the lookup value to be showed. currently I showing the calculation on SPAN.
The **var "multiplier"**

I try to get all input values and set them using below code.

```
function getInputs(selector) {
  var inputs = 0;
  $(selector).each(function() {
    $(this).find("input").each(function() {
      sum += parseInt($(this).html());
      $('#').val(parseInt($(this).html()));
      var multiplier = $(`table#${tableToUse} tbody > tr[product='${currentProductId}'] > td[volume='${volume}']`).text();
      //  $('#GrandTotal').val(sum); // give the final sum from Log
    });
  });
  return sum;
}
```

On the below codepen: https://codepen.io/dunya/pen/mojKNz
I am writing the final sum without any issues.
I would like to show the variable **multiplier** only.

I need hide the value=10 from user but show the variable **multiplier**.
My formula is like this:
the lookup value based on Product Origin, Geographical and Volume get the **multiplier(as Var)** I am getting that value:
 sum for single input =multiplier * input value(example for apple it is 10)
I just need to overwrite the input value with **multiplier(as Var)** for all 10 input fields, I tried using function still not get to far,
any suggestion or how to do it.
thanks.

```
<div>
  <label class="description" for="Apple">Apple</label>
  <input id="Apple" name="Apple" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="10" readonly="true"/>
</div>
```

As you can see on above codepen link, I have ten ID's such as Apple,Apricot .. so on, I make it read only. each has default value for Apple it is 10 and Apricot is 20 it is changing value, I also make it read only to proven end user to change it. my requirement change changed I will need show the value multiplier variable there instead of the attribute value such 10 or 20 so on, problem is I am using  value attribute to make the calculation work otherwise my final Grand Total calculation will be wrong. How can I resolve this. 
**for example** I selected Product Origin: Europe, Location: blank and Volume= 10, this 3 drop down gets me the look up table id called "Europe". the Volume will match to the columns to calculate for apple it will 0.1 * 10 (default value for id=Apple is 10) so it gets me 1 so on, Grand Total is Sums all calculated results on SPAN to give final value.
How can still use or store the default value for each input such as 10  so on but replace with  **multiplier(as Var)**  such the 10 input will display Apple 0.1, Apricot 0, ... and Coconut 0.1, also remember the default value?
the mock-up shows on image below:

Many thanks

[image]

Comment: I put some div id, like "Apple" as I want loop through and it will change that is why I leave it blank for a clue or suggestion

Comment: If you want to get help please explain your issue some more. Also give some context on what you're doing because I'm not sure at all. In your codepen I don't see any `value=10` which could be hidden. Do you maybe want to replace the inputs value with the calculated `multiplier` variable? If yes, please specify which because there are several.

Comment: @Elias, thanks for coming back, I added new section with example of what needs to be happen and what needs to show. I might need new attribute to store the default value and use it calculation but only show  multiplier variable which I get from based on 3 dropdown value as value=0.1 for Volume 10, if it is Volume 50000 it will be 14. I could not show the multiplier variable look up value on each input and still do the final calculation as correct on current version of Codepen.

Comment: Okay :D, so. You have a `multiplier` right.. where do you want to put the result / how do you want to display it and how do you calculate it?

Comment: Is there a reason you have functions in your functions?

Comment: If [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Elias_G/s5vpuwcm/10/) is your desired outcome please visit my answer. I've added some information at the bottom

Comment: hi Elias, it is almost there, there are two issue, 1) Grand Total shows "NaN" it should total from all 10 input, you managed to put the calculation from SPAN to input value, what I want is only show representative look up value on input field or the value of Variable multiplier not the calculated value, all input fields will be read only as default will not allow user to change it. thanks for your time and afford

Comment: Grand Total is not assigned in your code as well, just saying

Comment: Am I correct that you want to display the corresponding value from the table below? If yes there are two tables...

Comment: @Elias, yes, in real case I have 7 tables on Codepen I only showed to, it changes depend on the drop down, if Product Origin: Europe and Location drop down is blank it will use table "Europe", if Product Origin: Europe and Location=England  it will use England table for look up so on it will change based on drop down the line on my code pen "    var multiplier = $(`table#${tableToUse} tbody > tr[product='${currentProductId}'] > td[volume='${volume}']`).text();" the var finds correct value

Comment: I need use it to replace the input value, but use that input value or I can create data-set to store and loop through calculation, dont want confuse end user with calculated value. but need to use current Grand total as it is on my codepen.

Comment: Could you try to create a dataset and parse it yourself? StackOverflow is not here to do work for you but to help with questions =)

Comment: thanks for your time, I am asking question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it the issues, setting the value for each input was achieved by this line:

```
    // Insert result after the current input field.
    $(this).after(result);
```

and getting submit achieved by this line

```
 sum += +$(this).text();
 //console.log("Value sum "+sum);
 $('#GrandTotal').val(sum);
```

As I show all result on span I used this below to hide

```
 $( "span" ).hide();
```

**working version on jsfiddle.net
https://jsfiddle.net/erkindunya/L3d4j8hv/17/**

This might help one else who doing this

Answer (score 0):

**I'm using this answer to check if I got your question right so it will likely not be final!**

## Setting the Value of an input

If your problem is actually changing the input here are some simple examples:

```js
// ****
// ** WITH JAVASCRIPT ** //
// ****

// Get DOM Elements
const js_input_foo     = document.getElementById('js_input_foo');
const js_btn_change    = document.getElementById('js_btn_change');

// Add event listener
js_btn_change.addEventListener('click', () => {
 js_input_foo.value = 'New Value';
});

// ****
// ** WITH JQuery ** //
// ****

// Get DOM Elements
const jq_input_foo    = $('#jq_input_foo');
const jq_btn_change   = $('#jq_btn_change');

// Add event listener
jq_btn_change.click(() => {
 jq_input_foo.val('New Value');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--
  ** WITH JAVASCRIPT **
 -->
<h2>JavaScript</h2>
<!-- Input which displays a value -->
<input id="js_input_foo" type="text" value="100" />
<!-- Button which changes the input -->
<button id="js_btn_change">Change!</button>

<!--
  ** WITH JAVASCRIPT **
 -->
<h2>JQuery</h2>
<!-- Input which displays a value -->
<input id="jq_input_foo" type="text" value="100" />
<!-- Button which changes the input -->
<button id="jq_btn_change">Change!</button>
```

## Setting the value of an input according to dataset

If you want to set your inputs with looping through them this could help:

```js
// Constants
const dataset = {
  one: "new date one",
  two: "new date two",
  three: "new date three",
  four: "new date four",
  five: "new date five"
};

// Dom elements
const container_inputs = document.getElementById('container_inputs');
const btn_changeInputs = document.getElementById('btn_changeInputs');

// Add Event Listener
btn_changeInputs.addEventListener('click', () => {
 Array.from(container_inputs.children).forEach(child => {
    let key = child.getAttribute('key');  // Get the Key Attribute
    
    // If key attribute exists fill the corresponding entry
  if(key) child.value = dataset[key];
  });
});
```

```html
<h2>Setting the corresponding values</h2>

<div id="container_inputs">
  Input One    <input type="text" id="input_one"    key="one">    <br>
  Input Two    <input type="text" id="input_two"    key="two">    <br>
  Input Three  <input type="text" id="input_three"  key="three">  <br>
  Input Four   <input type="text" id="input_four"   key="four">   <br>
  Input Five   <input type="text" id="input_five"   key="five">
</div>

<button id="btn_changeInputs">Change!</button>
```

## Getting an attribute and use it in calculations for value

So setting the value of an element dependent of an attribute and multiplier would then be:

```
// **
// JavaScript
// **

element.value = element.getAttribute('my_value') * multiplier;

// **
// JQuery 
// **

// ****************************************************
// I STRONGLY RECOMMEND ONLY GETTING THE ELEMENT ONCE *
// ****************************************************

let element = $('#element');                           // Getting the element
element.val(element.attr('my_value') * multiplier);    // Setting the value
```

And the html element would look like:

```html
<input type="text" id="element" my_value="100" />
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion and your time to put together, let me try to merge the code and see if I can make it work, my problem is it uses default value plus the look up field will be changes based on 3 drop down. I think I can create new attribute "value_that_i_need " set a value "100" and use it 
 .getAttribue('value_that_i_need');, how can I set the "value" attribute it is my multiplier(as Var) <input type="text" id="foo" value_that_i_need="100" value="999" /> it will keep change but I am capturing it correctly on that multiplier (var)? I am still lost sorry. thanks

Comment: I would not set the `value` attribute. It is only displayed when the user has nothing entered yet **(AS FAR AS MY TESTING GOES)**. For example: if you have `value="100"` and then change it to something else with `element.setAttribue('value', 'foo')` it will only change when the user has not changed something. Even if he just deletes the value setting the attribute won't do anything **(again as far as my testing goes)**. To set the value of an input just use `element.value = 'foo';` or in jquery: `element.val('foo')`